# Is Fujifilm's "Super EBC" a modern nanocoating?

Tags: lens, fujifilm, lens-coatings, optical-coating

In the Luminous Landscape [review of the Fuji X-Pro1](http://www.luminous-landscape.com/reviews/cameras/fuji_x_pro1_review.shtml), Nick Devlin notes:

> ... how else could one read the “Super EBC” labelling on the lens other than as a nod to the company’s [Range Finder] past. For the uninitiated, it stands for “Super Electron Beam Coating” – a moniker devised in the days when men walked on the moon and words like “electron” and “beam” conjured up visions of a Jetson-like futurama.

The retro-styling of this camera is undeniable, and that's clearly part of its appeal, but the *other* part is very modern, innovative technology, like the dual optical / EVF viewfinder and the novel sensor array layout. So, underneath the [nod-to-the-old](http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6092/7028835671_81790bb383_o.png) naming, is this a traditional multi-coating, or is it [actually a modern update](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22151/what-does-a-nano-crystal-coat-do-on-this-lens)?

Comment: They haven't made a big stink about it, so it's probably safe to assume that it's a refinement of the "old" EBC process (which was not entirely meaningless—it's a cathode-ray regulated vapour deposition process that made a meaningful difference in their enlarger lenses over the previous multicoated version), probably using new materials. If they were doing something like polycrystaline crystal deposition, I think there's be trumpets blowing somewhere. Not definitive, so it can't be an answer, but it's the best extrapolation from the available data I can make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not. EBC is [described](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDwQFjAC&url=http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x_s1/features/&ei=AKr_UODpDsjZigf6vIGICw&usg=AFQjCNGWeU1i_yBC4_wR2VljjHbX-bB8YA&bvm=bv.41248874,d.aGc) as "multilayer coating":

> All the lens elements used in the X-S1 have been treated with multilayer Super EBC (Electron Beam Coating),

[Nanocoating however is NOT multicoating](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22151/what-does-a-nano-crystal-coat-do-on-this-lens), it is a different process.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness — Fujifilm lists [many lenses](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/xf_lens/about/ht-ebc/) which say "Super EBC" as actually using using High Transmittance Electron Beam Coating (HT-EBC), apparently first made for television lenses and [described in a FAQ](http://faq.fujifilm.com/digitalcamera/faq_detail.html?id=110201107) as:

> The low reflection range of this wide-band coating is the wavelength of 380 to 780 nm, while it is 400 to 700 nm for the conventional Super EBC coating. It reflects oblique-incidence light, greatly reducing ghosting and flare to realize clear images even under difficult lighting conditions.

HT-EBC is also a multiple coating process, not nanocoating. But newer lenses like the [XF16-55mm f/2.8](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujinon_lens_xf16_55mmf28_r_lm_wr/features/) feature "[Nano GI](http://fujifilm-x.com/xf-lens/en/coating/#1stPage)" coating, which, as the name applies, clearly *is* a nanocoating. (The "GI" stands for [*gradient index*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient-index_optics).)