# Is there a secret way to make the Fujifilm X-Pro 1's autofocus point selection faster?

Tags: autofocus, fujifilm, focus-point-selection, fujifilm-xpro1

I think the answer to this is "no", but it may actually be available and I'm just not figuring out how to toggle the setting.

The X-Pro 1 has a wealth of AF points — 49 in EVF mode and 25 in OVF mode. But the process to select them is cumbersome:

1. Press the `AF` button, located to the bottom left of the back of camera body, away from your hands if you are holding the lens so as to adjust aperture.
2. Move the point with the four-way controller
3. Press `AF` again to confirm.

Even if the AF button were more conveniently located, I'd prefer to not press it at all. Three of the four buttons of the four-way controller normally do *nothing* in shooting mode, and the `up` button puts the camera into macro mode, which I really don't want to be able to do so conveniently anyway (among other things, that switches the OVF to EVF until you turn it off, which requires more clicks than turning it on). So what I want is for the four-way controller to just *always* be focus point selection.

This was the default on older Pentax cameras, and on newer ones, it's an option whether you want the four-way controller buttons to do this or serve some other function by default. So, I'm very used to it and like it. Clearly, Fujifilm could easily do this with a firmware update, but before I make that request I wanted to make sure it (or some other shortcut) wasn't implemented somehow already.

Comment: This is not the first time that I read about a less-than-stellar UI for this camera... which is a bit of a shame since it aappears to be very good.

Comment: @Francesco — it's a quirky camera with a lot of amazing features and graceful, clever design — and also a number of drawbacks and quirks. Overall, I'd say the UI is quite good.

Comment: I read a review which stated more than once something along the lines "usually fuji is responsive to customer feedback and will hopefully fix this via firmware". I am convinced that it's really nice and only needs to refine some "rough edge".

Comment: I have found the review that I was referring to. It was Nick Devlin's on, and it linked in a question... by you :-) http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/22265/5032

Comment: BTW Matt, a bit unrelated but you may want to have a look at that: http://picabroad.com/2012/04/10/fuji-x-pro-1-autofocus-trick/ , I found that discovery kinda shocking (in a good way), if you are willing to break some habits.

Comment: @sebastien.b that trick was discussed very recently in [this](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22867/is-it-really-better-to-not-half-press-to-focus-with-the-fujifilm-x-pro-1) thread, also started by Matt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, no secrets.

Fujifilm clearly did see this as an issue to be solved, though, as newer models feature a perfectly-placed mini joystick which controls focus point selection.

Answer (score 3):

Needs a firmware update to address; obvious solution is to allow the Fn button to be programmed to act as the AF selector then at least it is easily accessible during shooting.

However, this needs people to tell Fujifilm that they would like this.  I called the FujiFilm Pro Digital team (1-800-800-3854 Option #1 and then Option #2) and they put me through to a person who said it was an excellent suggestion, took details and said they would pass it onto Japan for consideration.