# How do I get this sun-flare from behind my shoulder?

Tags: sunlight, ipad

I got out of the car to take a landscape picture with my ipad-mini-2. HDR was on. Afterwards, I hit auto-enhance and cropped it. Surprise, the sun photo-bombed my shot!

I didn't plan that when I took the picture.
Can I do it on purpose? Can I do it with a real camera?

[image: Landscape shot near Fuente Dé, Spain]

Comment: Remember when people told you not to let the sun shine directly on the lens when taking a picture?  Now you know why.  Don't do that.

Comment: OMG you captured a chemtrail!  :-)

Comment: @OlinLathrop why not? Sometimes it creates a nice effect

Comment: @laur: OK if you actually *want* that effect.  Most times you don't.

Comment: You can but if you do it too frequently it can damage your camera so be careful with this effect.  http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4016/can-the-sun-damage-the-camera-sensor-under-what-conditions

Comment: [How can you avoid/minimize lens flare when shooting into the sun?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/184/how-can-you-avoid-minimize-lens-flare-when-shooting-into-the-sun?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I do it on purpose? Can I do it with a real camera?

**Yes, and yes.** People usually try to avoid that effect, called lens flare, but sometimes it adds an interesting creative element. You should never point your camera directly *at* the sun, but if you frame a shot so that the sun is out of the frame but nearby there's a good chance you'll get some flare. Removing the hood from your lens will improve your chances of lens flare since the point of the hood is to block light from the side that usually causes flare. Other light sources, like streetlights, can also cause flare. Different lenses and different light sources give different kinds of flare, so experiment. (And again, don't point your camera at the sun.)

Comment: minor nit:  OK to point at the sun **if** you have a proper solar filter installed.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Agree, but if you know enough to buy the right filter, you know enough to understand why the advice doesn't apply to you.

Comment: Not to mention the cross over between shots using a solar filter and shots using artistic lens flare is probably small enough to safely ignore